# Does first slash is compulsory in URL?

Tags: url, curl, rfc, rfc1738

Today we had an arguing with colleague about if that would be a valid URL `http://domain.com?some_param=1`. The RFC that defines URL structure does not explicitly states that that is invalid structure. According to [RFC 1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), part 3.3

```
If neither <path> nor <searchpart> is present, the "/" may also be omitted.
```

However, at the end of part 3.1 of same document it says

```
Note that the "/" between the host (or port) and the url-path is  NOT part of the url-path.
```

Checking up with curl revealed some interesting thing

```
$ curl -v -I http://stackoverflow.com?test
* Rebuilt URL to: http://stackoverflow.com/?test
...
```

So, question is

Is this is a valid URL or not? `http://domain.com?some_param=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section 3.3 defers to section 3.1 for `host` and `port`, but the rest is as defined in that section. Thus, the slash after `port` is required if either of `path` or `searchpart` is present.

Nonetheless tools may attempt to extract a valid URL even with the omission of this slash, since one of the precepts of various ideologies is to be liberal on input and conservative on output.

Comment: Thanks, you confirmed my understanding of it.